# supporting different screen sizes in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have developed an app in Android Studio having 12 different images and I need to support my developed app in multiple screen size, so I have created different layouts such as small, normal, large and extra large even drawable folders too of different dpi, while executing my app works pretty good in tablet but it's not working for small screen size:

```
res/new/layout-small
res/new/layout-normal
res/new/layout-large
res/new/layout-extra large
```

drawable

```
res/new/drawable/mdpi
res/new/drawable/ldpi
res/new/drawable/xhdpi
res/new/drawable/hdpi
```

and I have  created `main.xml` layout

Comment: Have you solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The default path for ressources in a android project are res/drawable-mdpi res/drawable-ldpi res/drawable-xhdpi res/drawable-hdpi etc, you should try that instead.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please also add the default layout folder. May be it's not picking the resources from  required folder...